# Conditional formatting of text using wildcards in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting

I need to write a conditional formatting where a text should be italic if it starts with "  X". Otherwise it should be normal font.

How do I achieve string compare with wildcard? I tried the following:

```
IF({my_sp.field_label} like '  X%') then crItalic else crRegular
```

Any pointers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crystal Reports recognizes the `*` as a wild card in like comparisons.

From some [CR documentation available online](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/topic/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic901.html):

> Like pattern operator Basic and Crystal syntax.
>
> The Like operator is useful for selecting records to include or
>   exclude from your report.
>
> Usage x like y
>
> {fieldname} like "c?n*"
>
> This operator tests to see if the contents of {fieldname} matches a
>   pattern that you specify in a character string "c?n*". If the contents
>   of the field do fit the pattern "c?n*", then the formula returns the
>   value True. If the field starts with anything else, the formula
>   returns False.
>
> Use the wildcard symbols ? and * to stand for variable characters. The
>   ? stands for a single character. The * symbol stands for any number of
>   characters.
>
> Examples The following examples are applicable to both Basic and
>   Crystal syntax:
>
> {customer.FIRST NAME} like "D?n"
>
> TRUE, where {customer.FIRST NAME} = Dan or Don.
>
> {customer.FIRST NAME} like "D?n"
>
> FALSE, where {customer.FIRST NAME} = Doug or Rob.
>
> {customer.LAST NAME} like "*s?n*"
>
> TRUE, where {customer.LAST NAME} = Johnson or Olson or Olsen.
>
> {customer.LAST NAME} like "*s?n*"
>
> FALSE, where {customer.LAST NAME} = Johnston or Smith.

Comment: so if i do {fieldname} like "  X?" it should be true for "  X", "  X12345", correct?

Comment: no the `?` is a wildcard for a **single** character. so it'd be false for both examples. The `*` is a wild card for 0 or more characters, so that'd be true for `like " X*"`